# ng-keypress not triggering function

Tags: angularjs, keypress

I'm new to AngularJS. I'm implementing ng-keypress events in AngularJS.
I referred to many blogs and tried to do as it is shown, but my code is not working!

```
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <input  ng-keypress="change($event)" type="text" >
            {{ text }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

script is:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.change=function($event){
            $scope.text= 'a';
        };
    }]);
```

I'm trying to change the value of {{text}} on keypress.. but it's not working!
can anyone help me out!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i tried the same things and its working

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input  ng-keypress="change($event)" type="text" >
    <pre>{{name}}</pre>
  </body>


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.change=function($event){
    $scope.name= 'hello';
    };
});
```

checkout this plunker... [PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/iS45mWSHdZyFAWnfIxYD?p=preview)

**EDIT**
checkout [your code plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UYGCi5yN8VLV5Z16UGl2).. thats also working

**EDIT**

finally the answer is: 1.0.7 does not support ng-keypress, hence it was not working..

Comment: i used minified AngularJS script from google api.. i doubted it and changed to script u included in plunker!!
shockingly it's working. but why it didn't worked with this ( <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script> )

Comment: i dont think 1.0.7 had ng-keypress... [1.0.7 api](https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/docs/api)

Comment: ohh.. i'm using old release it seems!
thanks for your reply harish. :)

Answer (score 5):

sometimes ng-keypress do not work on some browsers !! 
i had the issue with the arrow keys in chrome 
try ng-keydown instead (it worked for me )

Comment: I encountered same issue. I have implemented type head plugin of boot strap with angular. And on input I have bind key press event. When I start typing before selecting then key press event was firing but when I selected a option from typehead and again started typing key presss event stops working. It works again untill I remove the whole text from input. I am shocked why it happening. But keydown event worked perfectly. This issue is occuring only on CHROME and EDGE.

Comment: Here is the code pen link  http://codepen.io/varinder_rai/pen/YpReBG fort issue which I have described above. When keypress event will be changed to keydown it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else says it's working as it is supposed to do. Perhaps you want something like this?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.text = '';
  $scope.change=function($event){
    $scope.text += String.fromCharCode($event.keyCode);
  };
}]);
```